# Windows 7: can I renew DHCP lease through GUI?

Tags: windows-7, networking, dhcp, gui, feature-regression

In Windows XP, there was a GUI option within each network interface to renew the DHCP lease of the interface.

Does Windows 7 Professional no longer offer a GUI to renew DHCP?  Else, how and where do I find it now?

Comment: It may automatically do it when you right click on the networking icon on the bottom right and click troubleshoot problems. Otherwise I don't think so - you'd just be stuck with the usual ipconfig /renew. However, I am curious why you'd want such a feature. Mind sharing?

Comment: Why would someone *not* want such a feature?  If you change the settings on your router, how do you get the new IP-address if the original lease was 7 days?  If the netmask/gateway is the same, and DNS still works, do you have to wait 7 days, and then have all your on-going connections terminate, since the old IP goes away on its own schedule?  Likewise, if you add a new DNS server in the router's dhcpd, how are you supposed to get it on the client?  Even OS X has a `Renew DHCP Lease` option.  Whom are we kidding, even Apple's minimalistic iOS has a `Renew Lease` option!

Comment: To clarify I was asking what the importance of it being built into the GUI would be vs. the existing command line option. For the sake of discussion though it'd be incredibly bad practice to just change over DHCP settings like that. I'd stand up the second DHCP server with the new range and configure the two networks to be able to talk to each other. Disable the old DHCP server to give out new leases and have the new one start dishing out new ones. After your lease period (for example, our 7 days we're discussing) expires then I'd start phasing out the old DHCP server.

Comment: @BradleyForney, You have to be kidding me.  This is superuser.com, not serverfault.com.  Having two DHCP servers is absolute absurd.  I'm not asking for a *GUI would be*, I'm asking for what has happened with the *existing* GUI that's worked perfectly great in Windows XP -- where did it go with Windows 7?

Comment: All I can offer is "because they wanted to". There's no real added value to the typical end user to have such a feature in the primary GUI. It's a power user/admin feature - thus it's accessible via the typical power user/admin interfaces (cmd/powershell). Worst case if you really use it all the time just script that command and put it on your desktop.